# Is it possible to make car drive on the opposite direction lane in the road traffic library?

Tags: simulation, anylogic, driving-directions

I'm currently doing simulation on autonomous vehicles in Anylogic. But the problem for me now is that I don't know in the road traffic library of Anylogic, if it's possible for the cars to change lane and drive on the opposite direction to avoid obstacles on the current lane(considering a road with one lane for each direction). Or is there any simulation software can simulate that scenario?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDVK1.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do that particular maneuver with the road traffic library. You will have to use the process modeling library (PML) to avoid obstacles and change lanes to the opposite direction. This means that you will have to construct the car intelligence in order to avoid collisions.

You can nevertheless use traffic library everywhere and mix it with PML in those particular segments, but that is quite complicated.

In general for autonomous vehicles it's better to use the PML... the road traffic library is quite limited.